# Issues with raising VOB feature level

Tags: clearcase

Are there any issues to worry about before raising the VOB feature level? Can it be easily reverted if it causes issues? Is it even anything to worry about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by "[About Feature Levels and ClearCase](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21119269)":

> VOB feature levels should be raised **only after all client hosts have been upgraded to the corresponding ClearCase version**.

So there is a condition to raise it.

> **Feature levels can only be raised to a higher feature level and cannot be lowered**.

So you cannot revert that operation.

This is using [`cleartool chflevel`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/t_vobadm_fl_change.htm) and [can be done even just for one vob](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21150579).
It prevents the use of new features which are not understood by client hosts with an older ClearCase version installed.

---

This kind of operation is generally done in the context of a ClearCase server upgrade, which means you backup everything first.
That is one way to -- not revert a `chflevel` but restore a content: you overwrite a vob with its backup, but that means you are rolling back the all ClearCase upgrade anyway.

---

Make sure to upgrade replica if your vobs are multi-site'd:

```
ct lsreplica
# if you see a replica named 'original':
sudo cleartool chflevel -replica 5 replica:original@/vobs/yourVob
sudo cleartool chflevel -force -family 5 vob:/vobs/yourVob
```

Comment: You actually can revert if you have a backup

Comment: @TamirGefen that isn't really a revert (i.e undo) though, is it. That is a _restore_